# How do I query this type of json?

Tags: arrays, json, postgresql

I am trying to query a table USERS with an array column NOTES in PostgreSQL that has type of json.

```
[{"notes":"testing note 1","createdby":"fname1, lname1","createddt":"2018-09-05T13:28:32-07:00"},
{"notes":"testing note 2","createdby":"fname2, lname2","createddt":"2018-09-05T14:40:06-07:00"},
{"notes":"testing note 3","createdby":"fname3, lname3","createddt":"2018-09-06T16:08:52-07:00"}]
```

I am looking to get the createddt of each note(s).

I have tried a few ways but keep failing to understand.

```
select json_array_elements(notes) as createddt from USERS -- gives me all 3 of the arrays.
select json_array_elements(notes->>'createddt') as createddt from USERS -- gives me a connection error.
```

Comment: Just as a mental note: if your database scheme is too complicated to perform such simple tasks, you should think about refactoring that scheme ;) Normalization has been invented for a reason...

Comment: I support that but I didn't create it, just doing customer support trouble-shooting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure how you want the output formatted, but if you want each createddt in a separate line, you can use json_array_elements along with the arrow operator:

```
SELECT json_array_elements(notes)->'createddt' as createddt FROM users;
          createddt
-----------------------------
 "2018-09-05T13:28:32-07:00"
 "2018-09-05T14:40:06-07:00"
 "2018-09-06T16:08:52-07:00"
```

In postgres 12, you will be able to use jsonb_path_query:

```
SELECT jsonb_path_query(notes::jsonb, '$[*].createddt') as createddt FROM users;
          createddt
-----------------------------
 "2018-09-05T13:28:32-07:00"
 "2018-09-05T14:40:06-07:00"
 "2018-09-06T16:08:52-07:00"
```

or jsonb_path_query_array to get the results in an array:

```
SELECT jsonb_path_query_array(notes::jsonb, '$[*].createddt') as createddt FROM users;
                                        createddt
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 ["2018-09-05T13:28:32-07:00", "2018-09-05T14:40:06-07:00", "2018-09-06T16:08:52-07:00"]
```

Comment: Jeremy, you are a life saver! <3 Thank you!